# Friends list request from Corona SDK on Facebook API returns nothing

Tags: facebook-graph-api, coronasdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-friends

I've copied I code I used in an older game into my new game (it worked and still does in the old game) that I use to get the users friends list so I could publish (send) a message to which ever friends I want, inviting to play against me in my game, simple enough, no?
But it seems this does not work anymore, is that true? Does Facebook only allows an app to request just the list of your friends who also use the same app? I can't see how this helps the gaming industry get the word out on new games using the Facebook API to message about it from one user to his friend/s...
Am a complete fool and miss something? can the normal friends list be loaded into my Corona built game using the Facebook graph API?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0 me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Facebook has changed the rules and the me/friends will only return friends who have the app installed.  You have to use various showDialog() features with friend pickers to see all your friends.